# Which of the following is the correct syntax for using the $q.all method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I received the question during the interview.

> Which of the following is the correct syntax for using the $q.all method?

```
•   $q.all([promise1(),promise2]]).then((values) => {
    …
});

•   $q.all("promise1", "promise2").then((values) => {
    …
});

•   $q.all({"promise1":promise1(),"promise2":promise2()}).then((values) => {
    ...
});
```

## Note: There may be more than one right answer.

Please help me!

Comment: How about reading the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)? -> _"An array or hash of promises."_

Comment: Plus, how could `$q.all` know what to do with `"promise1"` anyway? Unless there's some kind of DI involved, that just would not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and third answers are right.

The time will likely arise where you need to resolve multiple promises at once, this is easily achieved through $q.all() by passing in either an Array or Object of promises which will call .then() once both are resolved:

```
let promiseOne = $http.get('/api/todos');
let promiseTwo = $http.get('/api/comments');

// Array of Promises
$q.all([promiseOne, promiseTwo]).then(data => {
  console.log('Both promises have resolved', data);
});

// Object hash of Promises
// this is ES2015 shorthand for { promiseOne: promiseOne, promiseTwo: promiseTwo }
$q.all({
    promiseOne,
    promiseTwo
  }).then(data => {
  console.log('Both promises have resolved', data);
});
```